# How can I reorder Gmail filters?

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters

I have more than 20 filters, how can I easily reorder them?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Go to Settings > Filters.

[image]

This will result in an xml file.  You could edit the xml file to move the order of the filters, and then reverse the process and import them.

Comment: Oh dear, this sounds like more work than scrolling down each time ;-) Guess I'll keep doing that then! Though +1 for the solution

Comment: The Filter import/export it's now a standard feature. [Three Gmail labs graduation into standard features - Google Apps Update Alerts](http://googleappsupdates.blogspot.com/2012/08/three-gmail-labs-graduation-into.html)

Comment: It stopped working for me, now filters are imported in a random order (see https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/121474/why-import-of-my-gmail-filters-is-silently-failing )

Comment: I have multiple filters that tag my email based on the +whatever string I use on my gmail account. ex. first.last+whatever@gmail.com. I have a final rule that effectively says 'If there is no tag archive this message'. This ordering means rules appear in my iPhone mail app if sent to the correct email account and spammy-ish email settles into the base gmail account that I occasionally look at. This ordering has kept my gmail account usable on my iPhone until now. Based on the random order, messages may or may not make it to me, making gmail suddenly far less useful to me.  Anyone from google?

Comment: The disadvantage of this approach is that you have to delete existing filters first, and only then re-import. There is a risk you won't be able to load them back soon enough (network problem, etc). Even if all goes well for a short time some of your mails risk to bypass filters.

Comment: Be careful with this approach.  I checked the box to re-run the filters and deleted a bunch of emails.  I have a filter which deletes updates which are _older than 90 days_.  This only deletes email which do not have labels however it accidentally deleted some emails because the filter was applied first.

Answer (score 33):

Any time you save a filter, it goes to the bottom of the list.  Once you know what order you want your filters in, open each one in order, and just click Save without changing anything.  When you get to the last one, the filters are all in order.

Of course, you would have to repeat this if you ever really did have to change a filter.

Comment: Not anymore. It's in alphabetic order now.

Comment: Mine still behave as I described, and have not been rearranged into alphabetic (or any other) order.

Comment: Interesting. Are you using the (not so) new design? For me, it keeps them in alphabetic order even if I create new filters and there's no dedicated setting for changing this.

Comment: As far as I can tell, the design hasn't changed since I posted my original answer, so I'm not sure what you're referring to.

Comment: Ok. Maybe that's the difference. Google has radically changed GMail a couple of times since 2010 and gave the users the ability to keep the old one.
That's the overall new design: http://gmailblog.blogspot.hu/2011/11/gmails-new-look.html
and they've changed it several times since that time. (Including the addition of Hangouts support, the G+ integration, or the time when they introduced that tabbed layout with new internal filters and so on.) I don't know if you have all these "up-to-date" or if you can still opt-out of these updates.

Comment: This worked for me, but I had to change something in the filter. Just saving it without making changes did not move it to the bottom of the list.

Comment: Worked for me without changing anything in the filter definition. Thanks!

Comment: I edited a the first filter in my filter list. It went before the last one. The only "weird" is that the last filter included an extra comma. I removed it, then repeated, at this time, the edited filter moved to the end.

Comment: Confirming that this does work but only if you actually change the filter. (and 'update all current conversations' is not a change)

Comment: This does not work for me, using the "new" Gmail (June 2018). Even if I change the filter and save it the order of the filters is not changed.

Comment: Well, it's possible Google has changed the functionality in the 7 years since I posted that answer.  I haven't had reason to try it since last fall, but it was still working then, but that was before the "new" Gmail rolled out.

Comment: Only https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/111145/40259 works for me in 2019

Comment: It appears that they are now fixed in the order they were when they stopped re-ordering on save, but with new filters being added to the bottom. The following worked to re-order them for neatness (does not affect behaviour) - export as XML; reorder `<entry>` elements as desired; delete all filters in gmail; import from edited XML.

Answer (score 6):

As of this writing, if you are using the new GMail UI then the export/import approach to re-ordering rules no longer seems to work.  I tried all of the options listed in all of the comments on this thread and my rules appear in random order.

I also tried every trick I could think of in the XML file and could not seem to enforce any order.  The top line `<id>` tag seems to imply an order but also only seems to apply the order downloaded.

For anyone needing ordering of rules processing in your gmail box, please use the GMail feedback feature and copy a link to this Stack Exchange conversation into your feeback response.  It might be slightly abusing SO but if you also upvote this answer it might indicate to the GMail team how much interest there is in ordering rules.

In my case I include a `+whatever` suffix on any person or entity that I give my email address to and a corresponding rule to apply the `whatever` label.  At the end I have a rule that says `archive this message if it has no labels`.  Until today when I export/imported rules to add a new label, this has performed swimmingly to keep known, valuable email in my inbox and everything else relegated to the `whenever I care to review it` archived folder.

Gmail folks, I think this is a swing and a miss on rules processing.  Please restore control to me and predictability to how I sort my mail.  I understand Gmail is free.  I hope you understand how valuable this feature is.  I believe this is a case where real intelligence is still more accurate than the artificial kind.

Answer (score 3):

1. Export all filters
2. Delete all filters
3. Edit XML in text editor to reorder filters
4. Import XML

Editing the XML sounds like it is more complicated than it is in reality.

Comment: Not working in 2019

Comment: zeev seems to think this is not working. It would be nice if this comment could be more specific. There is a entry at a later date from Antonio below here that indicates zeev is wrong.

Comment: This is the only thing that worked for me today, also 2019.

Comment: Great to get this confirmed @lambart

Answer (score 0):

April of 2019 I found a fix. Make a "new" filter exactly as it was before, with one exception. In the "To:" field put an address that is different from before. Doesn't matter what it is, just has to be different, everything else has to be the same as the "old" filter.

Save it.

The filter should save at the bottom of the list as it is a "new" unique filter with the same specifications as the "old" filter. Once the "new" filter is saved, go back and edit the filter with the proper address and save it. It should stay at the bottom of the list, at least it did for me.

Hope this helps others as I was having issues sorting all the marketing stuff from my wanted email. This should work for other filters as well, although it is much more labor intensive.

Comment: Sorry, not working for me. I just tried the export -> edit -> import trick, and that worked.

Answer (score -1):

I just put a number as prefix & then it sorts automatically:

```
01_MyTopIssues
02_MyOtherIssues
03_Anything else
04_...
```

Comment: Please add a comment when down voting. Helps the new users understand what could be wrong with their posts.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but a problem with this answer is... where do you "put" the prefix. I see no place (in the UI) where you can put a name on your filters.

Answer (score -4):

Both the answers from *Pål Børsting* and from *AndyDan* did worked for me. But the original question was for those who **have more than 20 filters**, and i have 98. Obsviously, i prefer the solution to edit a XML file, as it is much more simple and scalable once we are familiar with this. Sorry, i can not vote neither comment your answers without the necessary points.

But the answer from *Rebecca Chernoff* did not worked for me. I think it should not be accepted as an answer to the question *how can I easily **reorder** them*, or it should be completed to work correctly. To reorder the filter rules, it was necessary to 'delete all filters' before to 'import XML', as it was correctly answered by *Pål Børsting*.

If a XML filter file is imported without previously deleting the rules, a changed rule filter will be at the end, as noted *AndyDan*. Although this behavior could be confortably acceptable by most users, the rules order DO modify the semantic effect of the filters (like mine) that have an equivalent of a **stop matching next rules** like in this example:

```
RULE 1:
Matches: (-label:zLabelToStopActions subject:EMERGENCY -subject:DGV)
Do this: Skip Inbox, Apply label "noc"

RULE 2:
Matches: (-label:zLabelToStopActions subject:EMERGENCY -subject:DGV)
Do this: Apply label "zLabelToStopActions"

RULE 3:
Matches: -label:zLabelToStopActions subject:EMERGENCY
Do this: Skip Inbox, Apply label "dgv", Mark it as important
```

This auxiliary label *zLabelToStopActions* was used just to give me the effect of a **stop matching next rules**. Without it, and if the ORDER is not exactly as shown above, the resulting logic for this filter can easily become unpredictable. For example, all messages with subject:EMERGENCY could match all 3 rules above, and do all these correspoding actions:

rule 1: Skip Inbox, Apply label "noc"

rule 2: Apply label "zLabelToStopActions"

rule 3: Skip Inbox, Apply label "dgv", Mark it as important

But the latest actions was expected to be done only for the messages that have not the word DGV in their subject.

As a final remark, if *Pål Børsting* agree, i suggest to invert the order 2 and 3 of his answer and, this way, to delete all filters only we are really ready to import them.

Comment: Please note that this is not a discussion forum. Only use the Answer space to offer a solution to the original question.

Comment: Well. You put me in a deadlock. As i noted in my first paragraph, i can not yet comment an answer; i tried, but i could not.

Comment: I understand you're eager to participate, but there's a reason there is a minimum reputation limit for leaving comments. See also: [Why do I need 50 reputation to comment? What can I do instead?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/214173/21960)

Comment: Ok, thanks for this link, i've just read it. It seems to me this site has a high level of paranoia, when compared with the reality; like Yahoo with its messages. That's one reason some people prefers Google, that has a lower level of paranoia because of a better treatment of its inputs.

Comment: It's not an issue of "paranoia" but a practical one of being able to find the answer to a question quickly and efficiently.  There may be some good info here, but it doesn't really address the question at hand, as Al has mentioned.  If you think there's some information that's worth preserving, you are welcome to ask and answer your own question.

Comment: No, my question was exactly the original one from Senseful. In my text, i point exactly the solution, don't you agree? The only solution to the original question, as i explained with details, was from Pål Børsting. The 2 others answers are answers to another modified question, but why do you accept them? In some other questions in this site i could find a much higher commitement with the original question, and with the reality, the facts themselves.

Comment: Do you think you are working to being able do find quickly and efficiently the solution, allowing 2 wrong answers at the top? These 2 answers are good for another similar question; have you tested them to see the results? Must i repeat that i mention an efficient answer to the original question?