# Can Gmail apply a default filter to a mail that otherwise has no other filter that will be applied?

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters

I know that all mails already have an inbox label applied, but I want the label exclusive of all my other filters.

I want to be able to keep track of all emails that will not otherwise be labeled so that I can simple click on the "other" label and delete them all at once or view them collectively. Deleting one at a time is a drag.

Answer (score 5):

#### Filter

You can create a filter that will act on all messages that are **not labeled** by any of the filters **listed above** this one (filters are processed in the order listed). Just create a filter entering in the field "Has Text" the following: `has:nouserlabels`

Potential issue: You have to make sure this filter is the last one on the list of filters. When I created it for the purpose of setting, it ended up near the bottom, but not the last one (to my surprise). Apparently, it's no longer guaranteed that the last created/edited filter will be listed at the end. (This used to be the case; see [How can I reorder Gmail filters?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/3840/how-can-i-reorder-gmail-filters))

And even if the filter is the last one now, sooner or later you'll add more and forget about that one.

#### Search

I think a better solution may be to bookmark the search link [in:inbox has:nouserlabels](https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#search/in%3Ainbox+has%3Anouserlabels) which will bring up unlabeled messages in the inbox. There is a [potential issue](http://googlesystem.blogspot.com/2012/11/new-gmail-search-operators.html) here too:

> You'll probably see a lot of conversations that have user-defined labels when you search for [has:nouserlabels] and that's because "Gmail applies labels to individual messages. In this case, another message in the same conversation thread has had a label applied to it."

If this becomes an issue, you can temporarily turn off conversation view for this search; there is a switch on the first page of settings.

---

I wish there was a search parameter like `conversation:off` because it frequently makes sense to disable the conversation view specifically for the display of search results. Alas...

Comment: A workaround regarding the conversation view is to use an IMAP client

Comment: Another workaround is to use Google Apps Script. See [Advanced Gmail Filters That Aren’t Available in Gmail](http://www.labnol.org/internet/advanced-gmail-filters/4875/)

Comment: What we need is a script that goes through the mailbox and if any message in a conversation has label 'foo' it applies it to all the messages in that conversation.

Comment: @SherwoodBotsford Why does not [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15681361) work for you?

Comment: If you reply to a message, your sent message does not have the label of the received message.  Now this message will show up in any search for has:nouserlabels.  I don't want to apply the same label to all unlabeled messages, I'm searching for a way to make sure that all labels in a conversation are labeled uniformly.

Comment: label:foo returns conversations where at least one message has label foo.  -label:foo returns conversations where at least one message doesn't have the label.  There is no way to find conversations where ALL messages or NO messages have a particular label.

Answer (score 1):

## Short answer

If your list of filters is short, create a filter for the complement of them.

## Useful search operators

- NOT `-`
- OR `|`
- Parenthesis `(` `)`

## Examples

### One filter

For`from:username@domain.com`
the complement is `-from:username@domain.com`

### Two filters

1. `from:username@domain.com`
2. `subject:"the non-wanted subject"`
   the complement is
   `-(from:username@domain.com|subject:"the non-wanted subject")`