# Is there a way to create a catch-all "if not in another filter then label as..." filter to Gmail?

Tags: gmail

I have many email filters connected to labels. I would like one final filter that labels every **incoming** email that wasn't caught by any other filter in the list.

Is this possible? Is there a hack I can do with IFTTT or Zapier if not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a little tough, as filters *seem* to be handled in the order that they're listed, but I don't think that's guaranteed.

If all of your other filters add labels, you could try creating a final filter with `has:nouserlabels`. That'll match any message that has one of your user-created labels, so ostensibly if any of the filters before that didn't add a label this filter would catch it.

If that doesn't work out, an IFTTT recipe that uses the same search term should find recently received messages that lack a custom label.

Comment: Thanks ale. That works great to capture the emails I'm after.  
Now if I could only get the filter rule to be the last in the list It would work perfect.  It seems, for me at least, that my filter rules are sorted almost randomly.  The newest definitely isn't added to the bottom of list as mentioned here.
https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/3840