# How do I make Gmail filters neutral with respect to archiving?

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters

I have several filters set up on a Gmail account.

- If A: apply label A, skip the inbox (archive).
- If B: apply label B, skip the inbox (archive).
- If C: apply label C, skip the inbox (archive).
- If D: apply label D, skip the inbox (archive).
- If E: apply label E, skip the inbox (archive).
- If F: apply label F, skip the inbox (archive).
- If X: apply label X.
  The filter based on X should not have any impact on whether or not a message gets archived.  **How do I specify this?**

A...F are mutually exclusive, but independent from X.
Any given message could have X or not, with or without any of the other designations.

When a message comes in that has B **and** X, the desired behavior is:
 - If B AND X: apply label X, apply label B, skip the inbox (archive).

But the actual behavior is:
 - If B AND X: apply label X, apply label B, leave in the inbox (don't archive).

Is there a way to specify the desired behavior in Gmail?

Comment: There's some evidence that the order of the filters matters. Is that the order in which they're appearing? Can you get filter X to the top?

Comment: I can't find any interface to change the order of filters.  Editing/changing filters seems to send them to the bottom of the list, but A...F actually goes on for hundreds, and making a change+change back on each one individually is a nontrivial amount of work.

Comment: Yeah, there's nothing in the interface to let you do that. Hang on...

Comment: [How can I reorder Gmail filters?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/3840/354)